# How to create folder in internal storage with I add more bitmaps inside the folder?

Tags: android, internal-storage

I want to create folder in internal storage with a number of images inside the folder. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

to create folder inside internal storage use getFilesDirectory();

consider the example:

for creating folder named myfolder in external storage:

```
File myFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myfolder");
if(!myFolder.isExists)
myFolder.mkDirs();
```

for creating the same in internal storage use:

```
File myFolder = new File(context.**getFilesDirectory()**+"/myfolder");
if(!myFolder.isExists)
myFolder.mkDirs();
```

now you can add files into the folder as you wish! refer to **myFolder** for the folder object.

hopes its clear..